# Backbone JS: Routes with empty parameters

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone-views, backbone-relational, backbone-routing

I have a route.

```
routes: {
      "example/=q:query": "example_main"
}
```

This:

```
localhost/site/#example/q=hello
```

works perfectly but if the URL is:

```
localhost/site/#example/q=
```

My router does not understand it and no action is performed. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

```
routes: {
      "example/q=*query": "example_main"
}
```